# Updating npm outdated packages on a react project, may someone plrase help me on the situation

Tags: react-native, npm, npx, npm-package, npm-outdated

**Package                      Current  Wanted  Latest  Location **
@testing-library/user-event   13.5.0  13.5.0  14.4.3  node_modules/@testing-library/user-event
web-vitals                     2.1.4   2.1.4   3.1.1  node_modules/web-vitals
**depended by**
ryan-mmbale
ryan-mmbale

I tried the following codes but did not work for me

```
rm -f package-lock.json
 npm cache clean --force
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the command

```
rm -f package-lock.json
npm cache clean --force
```

are used to clear the npm cache and delete the package-lock.json file.It basically locks or you can say preserves the packages versions in your project, which is of no use to you I guess.
You can use the command

```
npm update
```

it basically checks all the versions of the packages which are present inside your package.json and updates all of them.
Additionally if you want to update any specific package you can use this command.

```
npm install @testing-library/user-event@14.4.3 web-vitals@3.1.1
```

The version after both the packages indicates the version of package which you want to install.

Happy Coding  :)